# MSSQL remote connection failure over firewall

Tags: sql-server, windows-firewall

I'm kinda stuck, i'm trying to setup multiple instances on a sql server (seperate vm) as my development database, according to internet documentation it should be correct.

I can perfectly remote connect to my database when the firewall is turned off, but I cannot connect when the firewall is turned on.

So I know it is a firewall issue but i don't see the problem.

Every instance uses a different port.
I have enabled incoming requests to that port from tcp protocol,
I also have enabled ssrp.
I think the last one is not relevant or I should delete that one tough.

Any idea what i'm missing?

[image]

Comment: You'll need SSRP (udp/1434) if you're trying to use instance names in your connection strings instead of specific port numbers. It's the SQL Browser service that resolves those instance names to the TCP port numbers that the instances are listening on, it implements SSRP.

Comment: Yes, well the 3rd entry is the ssrp on the 1434 udp protocol, So I guess that should be correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: Try connecting to `tcp:<host>,<port>` for a specific instance that you've allowed in the firewall (do not include the `\instance`). If this goes through, the issue might still be related to instance name resolution. If it doesn't, it's more basic than that. Note that you must explicitly configure instances to use a specific port, rather than to grab a dynamic port -- the latter is accommodated by the browser service, but obviously not your firewall.

Comment: Also, if using instance names and so relying on SSRP, you'll need to restart the SQL Browser service whenever you change any of the instance's Server Protocol configurations because it only enumerates those as it's starting up.

Comment: strange, @AlwaysLearning yes I knew that after setting up the instance I have restarted the services,  On my networkmonitor instance on port 1440 it doesn't work, but on my fileagentstore on port 1441 I can connect. So I guess this is more ssrp related then? For the first instance I received error 258